# Multiples Explicit Waits text_to_be_present_in_element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

how do I make selenium watch two text elements appear on the screen at the same time?

The table I'm monitoring and dynamically updating via js

The way I did it just takes on consideration to the first

```py
WebDriverWait(navegador, 46800).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div\[2\]/div\[5\]/div\[6\]/table'), 'waiting for a call')),
```

My EC.any_of is ignored

my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from PIL import Image
import time
from skpy import Skype
from skpy import SkypeChat

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
navegador = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
# Dados de conexão da API Skype
slogin = Skype("***","***")
slogin              = Skype("\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*","\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*")
conn                = slogin.conn
contacts            = slogin.contacts
chats               = slogin.chats.recent()
# // Fim API
# Carrega a pagina que vou monitorar
navegador.get("https://cb10.td.commpeak.com/index/realtime")
navegador.find_element(By.ID, 'username').send_keys("**")
navegador.find_element(By.ID, 'password').send_keys("**")
navegador.find_element(By.ID, 'submit').click()
navegador.find_element(By.ID, 'selectedTemplateText').click()
navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div\[2\]/div\[5\]/div\[2\]/div\[2\]/div\[1\]/ul/li\[12\]/a').click()
navegador.maximize_window()
# Remove o modal do commpeak
elements = WebDriverWait(navegador, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div\[6\]/div\[2\]/a\[1\]')))
time.sleep(1)
elements.click()

WebDriverWait(navegador, 46800).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div\[2\]/div\[5\]/div\[6\]/table'), 'waiting for a call')),

WebDriverWait(navegador, 46800).until(EC.any_of(
EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div\[2\]/div\[5\]/div\[6\]/table'), '00:01:08'),
EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div\[2\]/div\[5\]/div\[6\]/table'), '00:01:09'),
EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div\[2\]/div\[5\]/div\[6\]/table'), '00:01:10'),
EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div\[2\]/div\[5\]/div\[6\]/table'), '00:01:11'),
EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div\[2\]/div\[5\]/div\[6\]/table'), '00:01:12'),
EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div\[2\]/div\[5\]/div\[6\]/table'), '00:01:13')
)
)

# Takes a print of the expected element in the variable element

time.sleep(0.1)
navegador.save_screenshot("images.png")
image = Image.open("images.png")
image.save("images.png")

# Runs sendMsg along with sendfile img
```